# How to set an entire row/column as read only in wx.grid (wxpython)?

Tags: python, wxpython, row, readonly

Following code sets a cell readonly, but how to set an entire row/column (for example 3rd column) as read only in wx.grid?

```
import wx.grid as gridlib

myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
myGrid.SetReadOnly(3, 3, True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use GridCellAttr to do this. Here's a simple example:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="A Simple Grid")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
        myGrid.CreateGrid(12, 8)

        # get the cell attribute for the top left row
        editor = myGrid.GetCellEditor(0,0)
        attr = gridlib.GridCellAttr()
        attr.SetReadOnly(True)
        myGrid.SetRowAttr(0, attr)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This code will make the first row read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but couldn't you do something like this:

```
rows = myGrid.GetNumberRows()
cols = myGrid.GetNumberCols()

for r, c in zip(enumerate(rows), enumerate(cols)):
        myGrid.SetReadOnly(r, c, True)
```

Or, even better:

`myGrid.EnableEditing(False)`

Comment: yes, but what if table has 10000 rows and 5000 columns? wouldn't it be slow?

Comment: You could also try: `myGrid.EnableEditing(False)`